# Changing pixel values in python (opencv), without knowing co-ordinates

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, rgb

So far my code splits an image into a grid and then finds the mean pixel values of each region of the grid. I am now trying to change all pixel values inside each regoin of the grid to the mean of the region, i.e. a 3*3 grid image would have 9 different pixel values.

```
# import packages
import numpy as np
import cv2
import dateutil
import llist
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import argparse

#read in image
img = cv2.imread('images/0021.jpg')
scale = 3
#get x and y components of image
y_len,x_len,_ = img.shape

mean_values = []
for y in range(scale):
    for x in range(scale):
        #crop image 3*3 windows
        cropped_image=img[(y*y_len)/scale:((y+1)*y_len)/scale,
                            (x*x_len)/scale:((x+1)*x_len)/scale]


        mean_val=cv2.mean(cropped_image)
        mean_val=mean_val[:3]
        mean_values.append([mean_val])

mean_values=np.asarray(mean_values)
print mean_values.reshape(3,3,3)
```

The output mean_values array looks like this:

```
[[[  25.91920573   32.65683594   79.10800781]
  [  47.4043099    67.91571615  159.6719401 ]
  [ 140.98916667  172.33229167  225.72739583]]

 [[  27.79309896   36.55742188  100.57583333]
  [  42.1552474    55.85042969  148.40445313]
  [  92.89833333  105.89760417  156.51497396]]

 [[  23.05854167   25.96677083   63.69509115]
  [  28.53105469   34.806875     98.81148438]
  [  30.2763151    35.97891927   80.45804688]]]
```

So the first element of the array would be the pixel value for the first region/grid/window. Looked all over for help but all examples seem to require pixel co-ordinates and I don't necessarily know them.

Thanks for taking the time to read :)

Comment: I don't understand, is there something wrong with setting the mean value as you calculate it? Use the `for` loop with the `step` option something like: `for i in range(0, len(img), step): img[i:i+step] = cv2.mean( img[i:i+step])[0]`. The only issue I see here is determining the step, and you're doing that just fine as it is.

Comment: @ljetibo Maybe my question wasn't clear, the code above works fine and I can calculate the mean of each window. What I am tring to do is take this mean value and make all pixels in the window equal to it. So using the mean_values array above, all the pixels in the first window would have BGR values of [  25.91920573   32.65683594   79.10800781]. Im not sure how to take the values from the array and apply them to the image.

Comment: That's what I'm saying to you. `cv2.imread` reads in an image as a 3D numpy array. All setting and getting is completely equal to numpy arrays. To access i.e. the blue channel of a pixel you would do a `img[100][100][0]`. To set it `img[100][100][0]=10`. To get\set the  **entire** first row `img[0][:]` or `img[0][:][0]=10` just like you would with an `np.array`. I currently am in win7 so I don't have `cv2` available, but I can get in linux and test that if it's not working, I don't see why it shouldn't. If `cv2.mean` doesn't return an array just use a `np.mean` which certainly does

Comment: @ljetibo - That works. No need to test.